# Inserting gujarati language data through mysql using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert 'Gujarati' language data into table using PDO statement. I've already one separate column in a table witch stores Gujarati names for a product. This works fine when I directly inserts data through PhpMyAdmin but when I attempt to update that column through PDO statement from a php file, it updates value with different characters.
I've already set character set as utf 8 in both the files but still it doesn't update the value properly.
Value in Gujarati language is properly coming in a file where query is executed. I tried echoing it, but just in Database, different character set is coming up.

```
$gujarati=$_POST['gujarati'];
$db->query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
echo $gujarati;  // This is printing Gujarati name perfectly fine
$query=$db->prepare("update products set name_gujarati=:gujarati where
productid=:productid limit 1");
...
$query->execute();
```

What is updating is this `àª•àª¾àª°à«‡àª²àª¾`. Any solution to this? I'm not able to find out any.

Comment: Sidenote: Missing ending semi-colon for `echo $gujarati  // This is...` which should read as `echo $gujarati;  // This is...` if that's part of your actual code.

Comment: That was typo & in the question only, sorry

Comment: Just checking. Instead of doing `$db->query("set character_set_results='utf8'");` can you try `$db->set_charset("utf8");`